# How to return a complex object from an axis web service

Tags: java, web-services, axis, fault

I am writing a simple web service to return an object with 2 properties.

I am embedding the service into an existing web application.

My wsdd looks like this.

```
<globalConfiguration>
    <parameter name="adminPassword" value="admin"/>
    <parameter name="sendXsiTypes" value="true"/>
    <parameter name="sendMultiRefs" value="true"/>
    <parameter name="sendXMLDeclaration" value="true"/>
    <parameter name="axis.sendMinimizedElements" value="true"/>

    <requestFlow>
        <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">
            <parameter name="scope" value="session"/>
        </handler>
        <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">
            <parameter name="scope" value="request"/>
            <parameter name="extension" value=".jwr"/>
        </handler>
    </requestFlow>
</globalConfiguration>

<handler name="LocalResponder" type="java:org.apache.axis.transport.local.LocalResponder"/>
<handler name="URLMapper" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper"/>
<handler name="Authenticate" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.SimpleAuthenticationHandler"/>

<transport name="http">
    <requestFlow>
        <handler type="URLMapper"/>
        <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler"/>
    </requestFlow>
</transport>


<transport name="local">
    <responseFlow>
        <handler type="LocalResponder"/>
    </responseFlow>
</transport>


<service name="helloService" provider="java:RPC" style="document" use="literal">
    <parameter name="className" value="ws.example.HelloService"/>
    <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="*"/>
    <parameter name="scope" value="application"/>
</service>
```

I am able to deploy it successfully.

If I try to invoke the method which returns a String, it is successfully returning the String.

But when I invoke the method which returns an object, I am getting the following error.

> AxisFault  faultCode:
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
>   faultSubcode:   faultString:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   Premature end of file.  faultActor:
>   faultNode:   faultDetail: 
>     {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   Premature end of file.    at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:424)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2765)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2748)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2424)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2347)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1804)
>     at
>   ws.example.ws.HelloServiceSoapBindingStub.getAwardById(HelloServiceSoapBindingStub.java:202)
>     at Test.main(Test.java:21)

Can any body help?

Answer (score 3):

I sorted this by following information provided at other forums.

We need to use `<beanMapping/>` if complex types need to be returned.

Thank you.